# Magento New Product Page Layout

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to design/test a new product page layout/template in magento. What would be the best way of doing this? Copy/paste the product view.phtml and rename it or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the layout or just the template

If layout you have to update the  handle

If template create a new theme and add view.phtml in the theme in catalog/product/ folder respectively

Assign the theme to be default theme.

Do some investigation to get some more idea about theme and layout

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly simple as there is already a built-in widget in Magento which display your newly products.

So create a new CMS page then go to content tab, click on insert widget, find "catalog new product list widget" under widget list and insert into page.

[image]